# AJAX y Query Wordpress, ¿como unir AJAX con una consulta Query Wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Estoy intentando hacer un buscador para una tabla que se genera a través de una consulta Query Wordpress, logro hacer AJAX pero no se como unir la respuesta de AJAX  con una variable en php para unirla al Query de WordPress, sé que es posible, pero estoy algo embotado y llevo horas con esto

Este el fichero

**buscadorProfesiones.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //AJAX
    function searchIdioma(idioma) {
        var parametros = {
            "BusquedaIdioma": idioma
        };
        $.ajax({
            data: parametros,
            url: 'procesoAjax.php',
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response) {
                $("#resultado").html(response);
                
                
            }
        });
    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="idioma" placeholder="Idioma a buscar"> <br>
    <input type="button" name="enviar" value="Enviar" href="javascript:;"
        onclick="searchIdioma($('#idioma').val());">
    <div id="resultado"></div>
 
</body>

</html>
<?php

 
require_once("../wp-load.php");
switch_to_blog(5);
// QUERY WP 
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'profesiones' ),
    'posts_per_page'         => -1,
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
    'meta_key'               => 'nombre_profesion',
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
                'relation'  => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'     =>  'organizaciones',
                    'value'   =>  $busquedaIdioma,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
    ),
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    echo '<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre de la profesion</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<tr>
                <td><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_field('plural').'</a></td>
            </tr>';
    endwhile;
    echo '</tbody>
    </table>';
endif;
wp_reset_query();
restore_current_blog();
?>
```

Este es el fichero que devuelve el dato

**procesoAjax.php**

```
<?php
echo $_POST["BusquedaIdioma"];
?>
```

Comment: El proceso es simple: 1) en `buscadorProfesiones.php` debes recoger los datos que quieres buscar, a través de un formulario o lo que quieras. Allí tendrías también el código Javascript que hace la petición Ajax. 2) En `procesoAjax.php` recibes el dato que se envió desde (1), por ejemplo: `$_POST["BusquedaIdioma"]` y usas ese dato como criterio para la consulta SQL, la cual **debe hacerse en `procesoAjax.php`**. Recuperas los datos y haces `echo` de ellos. 3) Los datos volverán a (1), pudiendo ser recuperados/mostrados en el bloque `success` de Ajax. Es así como funciona explicado brevemente.

Comment: y sintaxicamente, como puedo ponerlo en el success  para que se guarde en una variable php?

Comment: Hay un error de concepción en tu planteamiento. Es importante entender lo que ocurre con Ajax: hay una comunicación entre cliente (navegador) y servidor (php). El cliente manda a pedir unos datos al servidor (punto 1 de mi anterior comentario), el servidor recibe lo que le mandó a pedir el cliente, procesa la petición y la devuelve al cliente (punto 2 de mi comentario)  y el cliente recibe la respuesta en el servidor **en el `success`** (punto 3 de mi comentario). Significa que **en el `success` estás en el cliente, no necesitas ya nada del servidor**, por lo que no tiene sentido ...

Comment: ... querer guardar datos del `success` en una variable php. Dicho de otro modo, en el `success` ya tienes los datos que el servidor mandó, están disponibles en el parámetro `response`, como se indica aquí: `success: function(response) {`, ahora sólo tienes que leer/mostrar `response` **en el cliente**. Es fundamental enteder esa diferencia entre lo que es el cliente y el servidor, si no te encontrarás perdido y no entenderás cómo funciona Ajax.

Comment: mi intención es hacer con AJAX un buscador para la query de wordpress entonces en el meta query necesito el valor que el usuario inserta en el input y no tengo mucha idea por lo que ves de como plantearlo ni siquiera

Comment: Lee de nuevo mis comentarios y dime si lo entiendes o no. O si hay algo que no entiendes. Creo que lo he explicado de la forma más simple posible. Lo fundamental es que entiendas la comunicación cliente/servidor. Todo lo demás es muy sencillo, pero debes entender cómo funciona para armar bien tu código.

Comment: gracias, creo que ahora lo entiendo, creo que es de la siguiente forma: en el success debo eliminar la tabla ya planteada anteriormente al inicio de la tabla, y después hacer y display la nueva consulta query wp en el success?

Comment: vale, se puede hacer de la siguiente manera: en **procesoAjax.php** puedo ir arrogando la tabla?

Comment: Observa esto que hay en el `success`: **`$("#resultado").html(response);`**, si en `buscadorProfesiones.php` tienes un contenedor (un `div` por poner un ejemplo) como este: `<div id="resultado"></div>`, cada vez que la petición Ajax ocurra sin problema, ese `div` se actualizará con los datos que vengan del servidor. O sea, lo que significa `$("#resultado").html(response);` es *actualizáme el `div` con id `resultado` con los datos que vinieron del servidor (`response`)*... Lo que dices de *ir arrogando la tabla*, no lo entiendo...

Comment: aqui lo explico colega https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/395165/por-qu%c3%a9-no-me-arroja-la-tabla-dinamica-en-ajax-response