# ¿Por qué no me arroja la tabla dinamica en AJAX response?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Estoy intentando que se añada a un div una consulta wp, que displayea la tabla por echo y esta se añade en el success de ajax pero la tabla no me lo arroja no sé por que, aquí mis ficheros

**procesoAjax.php**

```
<?php

require_once("../wp-load.php");
switch_to_blog(5);

echo '<b>'.$_POST["BusquedaIdioma"].'</b>';

 // QUERY WP 
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'profesiones' ),
    'posts_per_page'         => -1,
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
    'meta_key'               => 'nombre_profesion',
    /*'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
                'relation'  => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'     =>  'organizaciones',
                    'value'   =>  'juzgado',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                )
            )
    ),*/
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    echo '<table border="1" class="tablaDinamica">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre de la profesion</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<tr>
                <td><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_field('plural').'</a></td>
            </tr>';
           
    endwhile;
    echo '</tbody>
    </table>';
endif;

?>
```

Aqui mi otro archivo:
**buscadorProfesiones.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //AJAX
    function searchIdioma(idioma) {
        var parametros = {
            "BusquedaIdioma": idioma
        };
        $.ajax({
            data: parametros,
            url: 'procesoAjax.php',
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response) {
                $("#resultado").html(response);
                $( ".tablaDinamica" ).remove();
                

            }
        });
    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="idioma" placeholder="Idioma a buscar"> 
    <input type="button" name="enviar" value="Enviar" href="javascript:;"
        onclick="searchIdioma($('#idioma').val());">
    <div id="resultado"></div>
 
</body>

</html>
<?php
require_once("../wp-load.php");
switch_to_blog(5);
// QUERY WP 
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'profesiones' ),
    'posts_per_page'         => -1,
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
    'meta_key'               => 'nombre_profesion',
    /*'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
                'relation'  => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'     =>  'organizaciones',
                    'value'   =>  'juzgado',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                )
            )
    ),*/
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    echo '<table border="1" class="tablaDinamica">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre de la profesion</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<tr>
                <td><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_field('plural').'</a></td>
            </tr>';
    endwhile;
    echo '</tbody>
    </table>';
endif;
wp_reset_query();
restore_current_blog();
?>
```

Comment: ¿Se muestra algo en este div: `<div id="resultado"></div>`? ¿Qué se muestra? ¿Revisaste la consola? ¿Hay algún mensaje o error en ella? Por lo demás, ¿por qué dejaste la consulta SQL también del lado del cliente? ¿O ese es contenido aparte que necesitas mostrar de entrada en `buscadorProfesiones.php`?

Comment: deje la consulta principal  en buscadorProfesiones.php por que necesito tener una primera tabla para mostrar y después la de la busqueda, que por eso la de la busqueda la pongo en procesoAjax.php, no se si esta bien planteado pero me solucionaba el problema que tenia de mostrar una tabla al inicio del programa, despues no se muestra nada en el div esta vacio, pero sin embargo si pongo un echo dentro del while, este se repite como tantas tuplas tenga la consulta, pero los demas echo no se muestran los que tienen la tabla y los get_the_permalink().

Comment: Prueba a poner esto así provisionalmente `var_dump($query->the_post());` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: amigo fue añadirle la linea:error: function( errortext) {
                $("#resultado").html("<p>Ocurrió el siguiente error: <strong>" + errortext +
                    "</strong></p>");
            }  y funcionó

Comment: Es raro, pues la parte de `error` que yo sepa no es obligatoria en Ajax/jQuery.

Comment: si que es raro... algo se me escapo entonces